# Returning an argument following a thread closing python

Tags: python, multithreading

Programming on the RPi and trying to utilize threading to get the most out of the small system. One problem though is that the RPi only has a quad-core and a gig of ram meaning that memory management is a must. Originally going to try and separate different functions into different threads; it reading the notes on threading makes it sound to complicated for my current level.

Decided to have one major thread create the smaller threads when needed to perform the processes. Problem though is I quickly ran into errors.

```
Exception in thread Thread-5:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run() 
runRecord = mp.process(target=mycam.RecordVideo())
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

As a solution, I thought of the major thread creating a second thread and once the thread finished, close the thread and starting the next thread. I don't know the best way to do this though. Can a closing thread populate a variable or pass a variable before it is terminated?

```
runRecord = mp.process(target=mycam.RecordVideo())
runRecord.start()
completed = runRecord.join() ???
```

code for reference as it might be a problem there. This is what caused the above problem

```
class myCamrecord():                                                            
# setup camera for threading
    def __init__(self, filename, resolution=(1280,720), framerate=45, RecLength=5):
        self.camera = PiCamera()                                                
        # setup pi module for recording
        self.filename = filename
        self.camera.resolution = resolution
        self.camera.framerate = framerate
        self.camera.hflip = "yes"
        self.camera.vflip = "yes"
        self.Recordlenength = RecLength
        print("Initialized Threading")

        # allow the camera to warmup
        time.sleep(1.0)

    def RecordVideo(self):
        self.camera.start_recording(self.filename, format='h264')                    
        # start recording
        self.camera.wait_recording(self.Recordlenength)                         
        # wait X amount of time
        self.camera.stop_recording()                                            
        # stop recording
        print("done Recording")
        self.TrData = TransferData(self.filename)
        self.TrData.Openport()
        self.camera.close()                                                     
        # close camera module

class TransferData():
    def __init__(self,filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.NextFun = "EOF"
        self.AckFl = "ACK"
        #Initialize the client socket for file transfer system
        self.TransferSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server = ('192.168.1.117',5650) # 'host static ip'
        self.TransferSocket.connect(self.server)
        print("Connected to:",self.server)
    def Openport(self):
        print("Start Transfer")
        f = open(self.filename,"rb")
        FName = self.filename                                                   # Put is a server side command to place file somewhere on computer
        self.TransferSocket.send(FName.encode())                                # send file name over to computer
        chunk = f.read(1024)                                                    # start pulling chunks from file to send
        while(chunk):                                                           # Loop while data is available in file
            self.TransferSocket.send(chunk)                                     # Send chunk from file
            if self.TransferSocket.recv(1024) != self.AckFl.encode():           # If package was not received, confirmation is receiving 'ACK', print below
                print("Failed transfer")
            chunk = f.read(1024)                                                # Grab next chunk from file for sending
        f.close()                                                               # Close file after sending all chunks
        self.TransferSocket.send(self.NextFun.encode())                         


filename = str(time.strftime('%Y%m%d-%H-%M-%S')) +".h264"
print("Record")
mycam = myCamrecord(filename)
runRecord = mp.process(target=mycam.RecordVideo())
runRecord.start()
runRecord.join()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `process` need to start with uppercase `Process` [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process)

```
import multiprocessing as mp

runRecord = mp.Process(target=mycam.RecordVideo())
...
```

**Update**

Difference between `mp.process` and `mp.Process` is that

```
mp.process # is module
mp.Process # is a Class
```

Comment: I did a quick run through the doc and it didn't explain the difference between "process" and "Process". when running the code it doesn't throw any errors. what's the difference?